# Get a DISTINCT list of values and count rows per distinct result return 1 for each distinct value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, azure-synapse

I am trying to get a DISTINC list of Statuses and then count the number of references per each status.

With the code I have currently the count returns 1 for each Status which is wrong.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(r.Status), COUNT(r.Reference) 
FROM db.ReferralUpdates r
WHERE r.Reference IN (
    122708,
122712,
122713,
122715,
122724,
122730,
122732)
GROUP BY r.Status, r.Reference
```

| Status | Count |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 1 |
| D | 1 |

And actually the result should be:

| Status | Count |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| B | 4 |
| C | 13 |
| D | 3 |

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a set quantifier_. `SELECT DISINCT` will give you distinct _rows_. Simply write `SELECT DISTINCT r.Status, ...` to make code clearer.

Comment: If you remove distinct and reference from your group by, you will achieve your goal. Right now you're just throwing random code and see what comes out

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to aggregate functions.

Comment: A `DISTINCT` with a `GROUP BY` is always a sign of a flaw in your query. A `GROUP BY` already causes your data to be returned in *distinct* sets, so if you are getting duplicates, it likely means your `GROUP BY` is wrong. Otherwise the `DISTINCT` is redundant and unneeded overhead. Here you just don't need a `DISTINCT``; just aggregate on your `Status`.

Comment: Hi @ThomA , thank you for the comment. You are correct, very silly of me, when I removed the DISTINCT the query worked as expected.